# Django Models and Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model called Circuit, in there I have a field 'name'.

And then I have another model called CircuitHistoric with a foreign key pointing to Circuit, and two dates.

Then in the admin.py I have a CircuitAdmin and I want to display the dates from CircuitHistoric with the property list_display.

I know that I need an inner join in SQL but is there a way to do it with Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `CircuitHistoric` model code is not available, I'll assume that the two date attributes you want to get are named `first_date` and `second_date`.

---

### *models.py:* `Circuit`

To display the dates related to your `Circuit` instances, you can define some specific methods in the `Circuit` model.

To get a the first date, you can declare this method (`self` being a `Circuit` instance):

```
def get_first_date(self):
    return self.circuithistoric_set.first().first_date
```

`circuithistoric_set` is the reverse `ForeignKey` from `Circuit` to `CircuitHistoric`.

If you declared a `related_name` on the `ForeignKey` in your `CircuitHistoric`, just use this value instead of `circuithistoric_set`.

`.first()` is used to get the first value of the collection of `CircuitHistoric` related to the current `Circuit` instance.

Now, give a user friendly name to your method:

```
get_first_date.short_description = "Start date"
```

You can, of course, apply some specific date formatting to this field.

This code will display the dates of the first related `CircuitHistoric` instance found.

---

### *admin.py:* `CircuitAdmin`

And then in your `CircuitAdmin` class, you can call this method in the `display_list` attribute:

```
list_display = [
    'name',
    'get_first_date',
    'get_second_date',
]
```

Now, reload your admin page and you have a new column, entitled `Start date`, that will list all the related data to the main `Circuit` object.

You will find more info about the `display_list` attribute in the [official Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

---

For your next SO question, please post your models code. This will make your question much easier to read and to understand.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, I am terribly sorry for publishing the question without the models. Next time, I'll do it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
# models.py

class CircuitHistoric(models.Model):
    date1 = models.DateTimeField()
    date2 = models.DateTimeField()

class Circuit(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey("CircuitHistoric")
```

In admin.py

```
# admin.py

class CircuitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'get_date1', 'get_date2')

    def get_date1(self, instance):
        return instance.name.date1
    get_date1.short_description = 'Date 1'

    def get_date2(self, instance):
        return instance.name.date2
    get_date2.short_description = 'Date 2'

admin.register(Circuit, CircuitAdmin)
```